# Move all new objects to declaration java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've got a really long GUI with around a hundred buttons that I created using windowbuilder. Windowbuilder however placed all of these new buttons right in the GUI however I need them to be at the beginning of the file in the variables declaration.

```
JRadioButton radioButton3_2 = new JRadioButton(""); //this is'nt where it should be
```

Is there perhaps a shortcut, setting, or plugin to move all of these new objects to the top?

Comment: What do you mean by "top"? This can't be in the first line of a Java file.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to declare the buttons before the method?

```
JRadioButton radioButton3_2;

gui () {

      ...

      radioButton3_2 = new JRadioButton("");

      ...

}
```

or do you want

```
JRadioButton radioButton3_2 = new JRadioButton("");

gui(){
      ...
}
```

In any case:

Easy solution:
use excel to create a list of

> JRadioButton radioButton_(incremental list);

copy and paste at the place where you want it in your code. Fix errors in method.